# PL/Sql REGR_ p-values

Tags: sql, oracle, linear-regression, p-value

I want to do do Linear regression SQL:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions132.htm

My question is how to receive the p-value for the coefficients? Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: the link to docs.oracle.com in your question seems to be broken.

Comment: I corrected the link, thanks!